# Stop threads in spring batch while using taskExecutor(asyncTaskExecutor())

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I have a issue here. When I am using this as my code (below) in spring batch configuration, my code ends successfully.

```
@Bean(name = "myStep")
public Step myStep() {
    int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); 
    int maxAndQueueSize = cores * 2;
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep").<A, B> chunk(CHUNKS)
            .reader(myItemReader(entityManagerFactory)).processor(myProcessor())
            .writer(myWriter()).listener(myListener()).throttleLimit(maxAndQueueSize).allowStartIfComplete(true).build();
}
```

But when I modify this code (for async writing) by adding `taskExecutor(asyncTaskExecutor())`, my aim is fulfilled but code is still running in the eclipse. Seems its a thread closing related issue. Please help how can I close my code gracefully?

```
@Bean(name = "myStep")
public Step myStep() {
    int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); 
    int maxAndQueueSize = cores * 2;
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep").<A, B> chunk(CHUNKS)
            .reader(myItemReader(entityManagerFactory)).processor(myProcessor())
            .writer(myWriter()).listener(myListener()).taskExecutor(asyncTaskExecutor()).throttleLimit(maxAndQueueSize).allowStartIfComplete(true).build();
}
```

This is the asyncTaskExecutor()

```
@Bean(name = "asyncTaskExecutor")
public AsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor() {
    int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); 
    int maxAndQueueSize = cores * 2;
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(cores);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(maxAndQueueSize);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(maxAndQueueSize);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("asyncExecutor-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```